# Unable to get the free endpoint for worker abc from 1 slots

Tags: apache, mod-jk

We have recently switched from an old Apache with prefork to 2.4.9 with worker, configured as

```
ServerLimit         16
StartServers         2
MaxRequestWorkers  150
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75
ThreadsPerChild     25
```

At the same time we switched from mod_jk 1.2.37 to 1.2.40.  Now we sporadically get:

```
20140625 18:04:29  [32187:139712338515728] [warn] ajp_get_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (3229): Unable to get the free endpoint for worker abc from 1 slots
20140625 18:04:29  [32187:139712338515728] [error] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2744): Could not get endpoint for worker=abc
20140625 18:04:29  [32187:139712338515728] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2806): Service error=0 for worker=abc
20140625 18:04:29  500  "/abc/search?xyz=2" 534b abc:- 0.200348s
```

What is 1 slot?  Isn't mod_jk supposed to dynamically configure itself to match Apache?  I found that under "high" load (after about 20 simultaneous requests) this becomes more likely to happen with more `ThreadsPerChild`.  Whereas with `ThreadsPerChild 1` it doesn't seem to happen at all, effectively reducing me to the equivalent of prefork.

Am I overseeing something or did mod_jk's picking up of Apache parameters break in 1.2.40?

Answer (score 1):

The doc for `connection_pool_size` says:

> JK will discover this number for the Apache web server automatically
>   and set the pool size to this value.

It turns out that this is not true.  It defaults to `1`.  Setting this to the same value as `ThreadsPerChild` made the problem go away.